# How to append once inside on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a jQuery on click function, and inside the jQuery on click function, Im using jQuery append. I want to append my value once, and when I click on that function again, I want to append my value once again. I been trying som tests, but is not working.

I have tried jQuery empty, and a if statement, but is not working.

```
jQuery("td.snapback").on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass("snap");
  jQuery(".snap .snapback-txt").show();
  jQuery(".snap").css({
    "background": "#cccccc",
    "z-index": "99"
  });
  jQuery(".formsnaps").show();
  var value = jQuery(this).closest('tr').children('td:nth-child(2)').text();
  //var value = jQuery(this).closest('tr').text();                   
  //jQuery(".formsnaps").empty().append(value);              
  jQuery(".formsnaps").append(value);
});

jQuery(".snap-close").on('click', function() {
  jQuery(".snap").css({
    "background": "unset",
    "z-index": "unset"
  });
  jQuery(".snap .snapback-title").show();
  jQuery(".snap .snapback-txt").hide();
  jQuery(this).removeClass("snap");
  jQuery(".formsnaps").hide();
});
```

When Im using my code, Its append the value, several times.

Comment: its hard to tell what is happening without seeing the dom you are selecting on.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work

```
jQuery('.formsnaps').append(jQuery('<li>').text(value));
```